# How exactly do aliases work in Oracle databases?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been dabbling around in sql code and recently was reading up on aliases. I am kind of confused why the following statement does not work:

```
select id, data from table1 a
inner join 
(
    select id, data from table2 b,
    (
        select id, data from table3 e
        where b.id = e.id
    ) c
    where b.id = a.id
)d on a.id = d.id
```

What I want is something like this to work:

```sql
select id, data from table1 a
inner join 
(
    select id, data from
    (
        select id, data from table3 e
        where a.id = e.id
    ) c
)d on a.id = d.id
```

Currently my solution doesn't have the WHERE class at the end, meaning all of the table gets fetched.

```sql
...
        where a.id = e.id
...
```

My point here, would be to use an ID present in table A in the table E. I'm open to suggestions as to changing the structure, but unfortunately I think the structure will have to stay the same since the actual query is much more complex. This is just an exert from the full query.

EDIT:

I'll try to elaborate as to why I have the current structure.

I have table 1 which contains ID's and text and other columns.

```
|    id    |  data  |
| -------- | ------ |
| table1_1 | text   |
| table1_2 | text   |
...
```

The second table contains multiple entries for an ID of table1.

```
|    id    |  refid   |  data  |
| -------- | -------- | ------ |
| table2_1 | table1_1 | proj1  |
| table2_1 | table1_1 | proj2  |
| table2_2 | table1_1 | proj1  |
| table2_3 | table1_2 | proj5  |
| table2_3 | table1_2 | proj1  |
```

What I now do is join the entries from table2 to a list of entries with:

```
LISTAGG(table2.refid, ',') WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY table2.refid) list_of_projects,
```

To use this, I need to use group by

My problem was, that I couldn't use the table1.ID in table2.refid.

Comment: It would help to post some sample table definitions, data, expected output, etc.  I can't for the life of me figure out what this is trying to accomplish beyond a straightforward join of three tables on the same `id` column which can be done vastly more easily.  You're joining old-style joins with ANSI joins which is generally terrible for readability.  You can't use the alias `c` prior to defining it.  Maybe you want an `in` or `exists` statement rather than a join but that depends on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: elaborate 'does not work'

Comment: @JustinCave what I want is to use the ID from table A in table E. And I misstyped. It should be where b.id = e.id. Basically pass the ID from the first select to the last select. Made some edits to my prior question. Sorry for being unspecific.

Comment: If you made a typo, please edit your code to correct it.  There are 2 `where` clauses and an ANSI join condition and I'm not sure which one you're saying is incorrect.  Theoretically, you might want to do an `outer apply` on `c` rather than joining to it but it sure seems from the limited information you've provided like you just want to do a simple join of three tables.

Comment: You should add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result..

Comment: @Turo the innermost select does not know of the alias A meaning when I execute the statement, I get ORA-00904: "A"."ID": invalid identifier

Comment: @JustinCave I think outer apply is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks, I'll look into it. I'm pretty new to sql so I have no idea about the major differences between outer applys, inner / outer join, cross applys and so on. So big thanks again. I'll edit my question to further explain what I was hoping to achieve with some testdata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12c, you can use `CROSS APPLY` or a `LATERAL` join to pass the outer scope into the inner sub-query:

```sql
SELECT id, data
FROM   table1 a
       CROSS APPLY
       (
         SELECT data
         FROM   table2 b
                CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT data
                  FROM   table3 e
                  WHERE  a.id = e.id
                ) c
         WHERE  b.id = a.id
       ) d
```

or:

```sql
SELECT a.id, data
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN LATERAL
       (
         SELECT b.id,
                c.data
         FROM   table2 b
                INNER JOIN LATERAL (
                  SELECT e.id,
                         e.data
                  FROM   table3 e
                ) c
                ON ( a.id = c.id )
       ) d
       ON ( d.id = a.id )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( id ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( id ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table3 ( id, data ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> ID | DATA
> -: | :---
>  1 | A
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=44715335bc7164eba06925ebaa664072)*

Comment: Lateral is actually the keyword that solves the problem I've had. Cross Apply also helped. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

For better understanding of how sub-queries work, just imagine that database processes them separate from each other.

It means the sub-query

```
select id, data 
  from table3 e
 where b.id = e.id
```

will be executed first. There is no alias b in this context -> an error

The next sub-query has the same problem

```
select id, data from table2 b,
(
    select id, data from table3 e
    where b.id = e.id
) c
where b.id = a.id
```

There is no data source called "a" -> another error

And to be honest, using sub-queries in this case is a bad idea. Join is what you need here

I believe something like this will help you out.

```
select a.id, a.data 
  from table1 a
 inner join table3 e
    on a.id = e.id;
```